# Does the function have a positive lower bound?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, irrational-numbers

Let $\zeta$ be an irrational number and $p, q, n$ be natural numbers. The function $g$ is defined as:
$$g_n(\zeta,p,q)=p^n|p\zeta-q|.$$
Does there exist a positive $r$ such that:
$$\forall p\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\},\ \forall q\in\mathbb{N},\ g_n(\zeta,p,q)\geq r?$$

Is the result relevant to $\zeta$ and $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMMENT.-The inequality $\left|\pi -\dfrac qp\right|>\dfrac{1}{p^{42}}$, valid for all rational $\dfrac qp$ with $p≥2$), is not recent, it is due to Mahler (1903-1988) and was published in 1953 twice in *The Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society*, 245 (England) and in *Indagationes mathematicae, of the Royal Dutch Mathematical Society*, 15 (Holland). This inequality, of an unusual character until the date of its discovery,("**striking inequality**" comments Alan Baker) indicates, with the limitations of its time, in what way rationals cannot approach $\pi$: every rational "close" to π determines its "distance from π", in the sense of never at a distance less than or equal to the power $42$ of its denominator.

**Definition**.- **The measure of irrationality of a real α** is the smallest of all reals $\mu$ for which there is a positive constant $A$ such that for all rational $\dfrac qp\ne \alpha$  with
$p\gt 0$ we have $$|\alpha- \dfrac qp|\gt\dfrac{A}{p^{\space\mu}}$$
**Theorem** (Liouville).-For every algebraic number $\alpha$, real of degree $n≥2$ there exists a positive number $c(α)$ such that $\left|\alpha-\dfrac qp\right|>\dfrac{c(α)}{p^n}$ is true for all rational  $\dfrac qp$  ($\space p>0$).

In other words, the measure of irrationality of the algebraic irrational $\alpha$ cannot be greater than its degree (it is quite less, but you had to wait until **1955** to find out). It was this theorem that allowed the Liouville transcendental numbers to be explicitly defined.

I give a succinct account of the progress in the value of $n$.

►Joseph Liouville (1809-1882), French: approximation $n+ϵ$, in 1844.

►Axel Thue (1863-1922), Norwegian: approximation $\dfrac n2 + 1 + ϵ$, in 1909.

►Carl Ludwig Siegel (1896-1981), German: approximation $2\sqrt n + ϵ$, in 1929. Siegel conjectured the best bound later found by Roth.

Freeman John Dyson (1923-), British-American: approximation $\sqrt{2n} + ϵ$, in 1947.

Klaus Friedrich Roth (1925-), German-British: $2 + ϵ$ approximation, in 1955. The best level, a profound result that earned Roth the Fields Medal. "*The achievement is one that speacks for itself: it closes a chapter , and a new chapter is now opened. Roth’s theorem settles a question which is both of a fundamental nature and of extreme difficulty. It will stand as a landmark in mathematics for as long as mathematics is cultivated"* (Harold Davenport, from his presentation by Roth for the Fields Medal at the Edinburgh International Congress, 1958).

Comment: This note was extracted from a paper (**Una extraordinaria acotación inferior**) I did for the Journal of the Venezuelan Mathematical Society. Due to distraction, some words in Spanish left me, the same ones that I happened to correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no lower bound.

Consider an increasing sequence $e_i$ of positive integers and let $b$ be a positive integer. Then
$$\zeta = \sum_i b^{-e_i}$$
will be irrational if the $e_i$ are chosen not to result in a periodic tail for the base-$b$ expansion of $\zeta$.

But $$\min_q g_n(\zeta, b^{e_k}, q) = \sum_{i > k}b^{(n+1)e_k-e_i}$$
and no matter what $n, k, r$ we choose, there will be sequences with $e_{k+1}$ large enough to make that remainder smaller than $r$.

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot. Though I’m still confused about whether or not, for every irrational $\zeta$, $g$ has no positive lower bound?

Comment: @JihaiZhu - An arithmetic sequence is one where the difference between adjacent values is constant. A periodic sequence would be one that repeats itself. An arithmetic sequence of exponents will result in a number $\zeta$ that has a periodic sequence of digits in its base-$b$ expansion. A periodic sequence of exponents would result in $\zeta = \infty$. Take care when you edit someone else's posts. Also, you should only edit to correct errors, not add additional content.

Comment: Sorry. I’ve learned the norm of editing next time.

Comment: How about number $0.101101101\dots$? It seems like every tail of $\{e_i\}$ is not arithmetic.

Comment: What I've shown is that for any choice of $r$ and $n$, there exists $\zeta, p, q$ with $g_n(\zeta, p, q) < r$. There are surely $\zeta$ for which $g_n(\zeta, p, q)$ is bounded below. You can construct them much as I have the counter-example here.

Comment: You are correct about that. Arithmetic is not the only possibility that will lead to a periodic expansion. I'll have to tighten up the wording. Still the idea works. You can always pick the $e_i$ in such a way to get an irrational number, while choosing gaps between adjacent digits big enough to get below any desired lower bound.

Comment: And $min_q|b^{e_k}\zeta-q|=min_q|\sum_ib^{e_k-e_i}-q|=\sum_{i>k}b^{e_k-e_i}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jihai Zhu.- Long before 1844 it was known that the set of algebraic numbers was countable and consequently that the set of transcendentals had the power of the continu. But the first transcendent number that was known was discovered by Liouville deduced from his theorem on diophantic approximate was $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{k!}}$$ Is this the number you mention in your comment?

Comment: @Piquito No...I’ was discussing with Sinclair about some details in his answer. It can be deduced from Liouville’s approximation theorem that the number you mentioned and $\zeta$ in Sinclair’s answer are examples of transcendent number. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @JihaiZhu - It doesn't matter now, but you are correct about the algebra. I was too quick in my earlier [reply.